# CSS position fixed to the bottom of a DIV section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have an arrow fixed to the bottom of a div section , but for some reason its not working ,

here is my html code:

```
    <section>
         <div style="margin:auto; text-align: center; position:relative; width:61px">
                     <a class="scroller-arrow"  href="#offset2"></a>
              </div>
       </section>
```

The CSS code :

```
    section { 
    padding: 10%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url("/images/text-bar-strip.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 393px;
    }

    .scroller-arrow 
    {
     background-image: url("/images/down-arrow.png");
     cursor: pointer;
     display: block;
     height: 61px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 61px;
     position:fixed;
     bottom:-11px;
     }
```

its always showing at the bottom of my screen not the bottom of the section ?
Could you help me much appreciated :)

Comment: works fine for me DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/37n3A/

Comment: could you add code above and below <section> , its not really going at the bottom of my section it looks like its at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clearing things up in the discussion, I believe this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/WBF6s/

Changes include:

- Removing the `div`.
- Setting `position:relative` on the `section`.
- Setting the `a` to be `position:absolute` and `display:inline-block`.
- Setting the `a` to `left:0`, `right:0`, `bottom:0`, and `margin:0 auto`.

Comment: but absolute I have to specify the top , right , left position and I need it centered and fixed without a change when resizing the browser

Comment: If the width is fixed, setting `margin:0 auto` as you have will center with `position:absolute`.

Comment: Do I need that bottom:-11px? I need it to go to the bottom of my Section Div

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52332/discussion-between-dta-and-user3150060)

Comment: `left:0`, `right:0`, `margin:0 auto` is the magic incantation which makes it center-aligned.  Without the `left` and `right`, it will be left-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

as an FYI, `position:fixed` is reserved for placing an element on the screen regardless of the other elements there.  It will fix itself to the window no matter what.  If you would like it to be stuck at the bottom (or top or anything) of an element, you need to use `position:absolute`.  The caveat with `position:absolute` is that you will always need its parent to have a position on it.  The most non-destructive way is to give your parent `position:relative` and this will make sure that the parent is always in the same spot.

I've made a very quick jsfiddle to show you what's wrong:
http://jsfiddle.net/AuGe2/

When you want to position something to the bottom of an element, you need it to be

```
.arrow{
    height:40px;
    width:40px
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-20px //Or half the width of the element
}
```

Notice the `left:50%` and `margin-left:-20px` This is what centers an absolute element in a box.  You are moving the element 50% of the way over of the parent's width, then you need to back-track a bit because it's moving the left-most side of the element.  You backtrack by subtracting the same margin at half the size of the element. You can do the same with top as well.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed`, places the element relative to the window.

With `position:absolute`, the element will be moved relative to the nearest *positioned parent*, which means that the container must have itself a `position` property set.

What we usually do is make the container relatively positioned, by setting its `position` property to `relative`.

So, you should make your `section` or your `div` relative, and your arrow absolute.